# SQL query won't run because of syntax error

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
MERGE INTO PATRON_STATISTICS AS Target
USING PATRON AS Source ON Source.PATRON_id = Target.PATRON_id

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (Patron_id, First_name , Last_Name, Number_of_Items, Number_of_Purchases)
    VALUES (Source.Patron_id, Source.First_name, Last_Name, 0, 0)

WHEN MATCHED AND Source.Last_Name <> Target.Last_Name THEN 
    UPDATE 
        SET Target.First_name = Source.First_name,
            Target.Last_Name = Source.Last_Name;
```

Whenever I run this code I get this error:

> Error at Command Line : 165 Column : 30
> Error report -
> ORA-02012: missing USING keyword
> 02012. 00000 -  "missing USING keyword"

I'm not exactly sure what's wrong. I have originally been merging tables like this but it seems to be a syntax error I can't figure out. I'm running this in Oracle SQL developer.

I'm using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: In Oracle SQL, a table alias must immediately follow the table name, without the word "AS". Remove it in both places. Also put the ON condition in parentheses, they are mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the syntax diagram for [Oracle's `merge` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606).  It appears to me that you're looking at a syntax diagram for a different database engine (what you posted looks to me like valid SQL Server syntax but it could also be valid on some other database engines).

- Don't use `as` before the alias
- Add parenthesis around the `on` clause
- Move the `where` clause into the `update` statement
- There is no `by target` clause in the `when not matched`

So I believe you want something like this

```
MERGE INTO PATRON_STATISTICS Target
  USING PATRON Source
  ON( Source.PATRON_id = Target.PATRON_id )
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN
  INSERT (Patron_id, First_name , Last_Name, Number_of_Items ,Number_of_Purchases)
    VALUES (Source.Patron_id,Source.First_name, Source.Last_Name,0,0)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET Target.First_name = Source.First_name,
      Target.Last_Name = Source.Last_Name
 WHERE Source.Last_Name <> Target.Last_Name ;
```